# How to set the FALSE condition in ifelse so that it keeps the original value

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I am looking to use the ifelse() with mutate(), and if the condition is false, leave the value what is. Here is what I am working with:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(column1 = ifelse(is.na(column1), 0, "insert code to do nothing"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df <- df %>% mutate(column1 = ifelse(is.na(column1), 0, column1))
```

Note you also more directly use the `recode` function to turn missings into 0.

Or you can also use:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(column1 = replace_na(column1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of options -

1. Base R -

```
df$column1[is.na(df$column1)] <- 0
```

2. Using `dplyr` `coalesce` -

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(column1 = coalesce(column1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[is.na(column1), column1 := 0]
```

---

Or in `dplyr` with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
        mutate(column1 = case_when(is.na(column1) ~ 0, TRUE ~ column1))
```